# how to add volume level to videojs 7.9.6

Tags: video.js

I have script design with videojs player
in the control bar the volume button only mute & unmute
I want it to show volume level instead to allow for visitor to level up to level down the volume

any help for how i can make this

Answer (score 0):

"Hii @fady-sawairas You can refer to :

1. https://docs.videojs.com/volumelevel
2. https://docs.videojs.com/volumecontrol
3. https://docs.videojs.com/volumebar

this will explain it much better than we can in an answer here.”

Comment: thanks sukant but can you help me to how i will import this new JS files on the orignal videojs.min.js

Comment: @FadySawairas can refer to [link] (https://videojs.com/getting-started/) for better understanding